# I'm new but I still can answer questions right? The captcha won't load

Tags: support, new-users

I would like to answer a question but the captcha won't load so I can't. Does this have to do with cookies and what not. It usually does. No one has answered it yet. Not sure if that matters. I can't find anyplace where it talks about the captcha. I have answered on question but I wasn't the first to do so.

Comment: Are your cookies enabled?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. New users *should* be able to answer questions. I've retagged this report as a bug, which should catch the attention of the developers. In the meantime, try posting an answer again from a different browser.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought.

Comment: I tried to allow cookies for this site but still the same thing happens. I don't want to have them on my computer and I should have to enable them just for this site.

Answer (score 4):

You say you have cookies blocked, but have allowed them for this site. However, the captcha is ReCAPTCHA, which is an external service, so the cookies are not from this site. You may need to whitelist that, too. Another option might be to allow cookies from all domains, but set your browser to clear them on shutdown.